# list of any collection type, also with a generic data type

Tags: java, list, object, generics

I'm trying to modify the class below so its functions accept any from of collection the data type of those collection is also generic, allowing for maximally flexible:

```
public class Container<E> {
   List<E> cont;
   public Container() { 
        cont = new java.util.LinkedList<T>(); 
   }
   void add(E item) {
        cont.add(item);
   }
   public E remove() {
        return cont.remove(0);
   }
   void addMulti(List<E> items) {
        for (E elem : items) {
              cont.add(elem);
        } 
   }
   void removeMulti(int x, List<E> items) {
        for (E elem : cont.subList(0, n)) {
              items.add(elem);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<x; ++i) cont.remove(0);
   }
}
```

I'm trying to make List accept multiple types using wildcard, like:

```
 List<?> //Right??
```

In addition, the addAll, and removeAll function should accept any kind of lists as an argument, instead of List only, could t be like:

```
Collection<?> //Correct???
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: ...and the problem statement?

Comment: I'm trying to make List<E> accept multiple types using wildcard, like List<?> ??  In addition, the addAll, and removeAll function should accept any kind of lists as an argument, instead of List only, like Collection<?> ???

Comment: Sorry guys for not being clear. I really appreciate your help! I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `addMulti`, you do not want to accept a `Collection<?>`, because you cannot rightly say it contains elements compatible with `E`. For maximum generality, you might accept a `Collection<? extends E>`, which says that the collection contains `E` or some subclass of `E`.

```
void addMulti(Collection<? extends E> items) {...}
```

For `removeMulti`, yes, you could accept a `Collection<?>`, because if the type of some element in the collection is not compatible with `E`, it will simply not be removed.

```
void removeMulti(int x, Collection<?> items) {...}
```

Though, if you take a wildcard collection in `removeMulti`, you will not be able to add to `items`. (I don't really understand what your code is supposed to do there.)

This is the way [`Collection#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) and [`Collection#removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) are defined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How should I declare List<E> cont then? Shall I keep it the same?

Comment: The code is an assignment. It is not meant to do anything!

Comment: As far as I can tell, `List<E>` was appropriate for `cont`. We only use a wildcard when we don't particularly care what the type is. `Collection<?>` is sort of like `Collection<don't know/don't care>`.